How do I register screen rotation event on Pixel 6a emulator using NDK?
I am trying to detect a screen rotation on my device. I have the following...
void handle_cmd(android_app *pApp, int32_t cmd) {
    aout << "Got Command " << cmd << std::endl;
    switch (cmd) {
        case APP_CMD_INIT_WINDOW:
            // A new window is created, associate a renderer with it. You may replace this with a
            // "game" class if that suits your needs. Remember to change all instances of userData
            // if you change the class here as a reinterpret_cast is dangerous this in the
            // android_main function and the APP_CMD_TERM_WINDOW handler case.
            pApp->userData = new Renderer(pApp);
            break;
        case APP_CMD_TERM_WINDOW:
            // The window is being destroyed. Use this to clean up your userData to avoid leaking
            // resources.
            //
            // We have to check if userData is assigned just in case this comes in really quickly
            if (pApp->userData) {
                //
                auto *pRenderer = reinterpret_cast<Renderer *>(pApp->userData);
                pApp->userData = nullptr;
                delete pRenderer;
            }
            break;
        case APP_CMD_CONFIG_CHANGED:
            // The current device configuration has changed.
            aout << "Device configuration has changed (e.g., orientation)" << std::endl;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

When I run in the emulator and rotate the screen (and click the icon ;-)), I don't see the Device configuration has changed in logcat. If I examine the events fired I see...
...  AO                      com.example.testapp                  D  Got Command 13
...  AO                      com.example.testapp                  D  Got Command 2
...  AO                      com.example.testapp                  D  Got Command 14
...  AO                      com.example.testapp                  D  Got Command 12
...  AO                      com.example.testapp                  D  Got Command 15
...  AO                      com.example.testapp                  D  Got Command 10
...  AO                      com.example.testapp                  D  Got Command 11
...  AO                      com.example.testapp                  D  Got Command 16
...  AO                      com.example.testapp                  D  Got Command 16
...  AO                      com.example.testapp                  D  Got Command 1
...  AO                      com.example.testapp                  D  Got Command 3
...  AO                      com.example.testapp                  D  Got Command 4
...  AO                      com.example.testapp                  D  Got Command 6
...  AO                      com.example.testapp                  D  Got Command 16

This also doesn't show APP_CMD_CONFIG_CHANGED which should be 8. So which one of these events SHOULD I use to register the state change? Also is there a page that shows the numeric value of each of these enums?

This might only work prior to Android Oreo and on the issue-tracker it's also flagged as "won't fix".
The suggested workaround is to override onConfigurationChanged() in Java and then call to JNI.
And to answer the actual question... yes, these constants have been documented (it's an enum):
https://developer.android.com/reference/games/game-activity/group/android-native-app-glue
APP_CMD_CONFIG_CHANGED is even still listed there and it seems to be handled in android_native_app_glue.c, but it's useless, unless being triggered by the Activity.

The strange part is, that the (assumed) class NativeActivity features that JNI call and also the relevant documentation has it. There's two options: either the configuration-change event it is not being registered in AndroidManifest.xml - or the Activity does not properly call to JNI.
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (! this.isDestroyed()) {
        this.onConfigurationChangedNative(this.getGameActivityNativeHandle(), newConfig);
    }
}


It is also required to set propteryandroid:configChanges on the activity node;
else lifecycle method onConfigurationChanged() won't be called by the OS.
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:exported="true"/>


FYI this is a pixel 6a emulator and I was more refering to how I map the enum to the int as opposed to where is the docs but thanks for the awesome answer.

"pixel 6a emulator" does not say the least about the version of the image it is running - nor does the question indicate which Activity your are using. When the event is not being triggered, it's usually just not registered in the manifest.
